# Pytorch: backpropagating from sum of matrix elements to leaf variable

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

I'm trying to understand backpropagation in pytorch a bit better. I have a code snippet that successfully does backpropagation from the output d to the leaf variable a, but then if I add in a reshape step, the backpropagation no longer gives the input a gradient.

I know reshape is out-of-place, but I'm still not sure how to contextualize this.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

```
#Works
a = torch.tensor([1.])
a.requires_grad = True
b = torch.tensor([1.])
c = torch.cat([a,b])
d = torch.sum(c)
d.backward()

print('a gradient is')
print(a.grad) #=> Tensor([1.])

#Doesn't work
a = torch.tensor([1.])
a.requires_grad = True
a = a.reshape(a.shape)
b = torch.tensor([1.])
c = torch.cat([a,b])
d = torch.sum(c)
d.backward()

print('a gradient is')
print(a.grad) #=> None
```

Comment: what do you mean by contextualizing?

Comment: Just wanted some bigger picture of what was going wrong here, as Sergey provided. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

Here is a detailed explanation of what's going on ("this isn't a bug per se, but it is definitely a source of confusion"): https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19778

So one solution is to specifically ask to retain grad for now non-leaf `a`:

```
a = torch.tensor([1.])
a.requires_grad = True
a = a.reshape(a.shape)
a.retain_grad()
b = torch.tensor([1.])
c = torch.cat([a,b])
d = torch.sum(c)
d.backward()
```

---

Old answer:

If you move `a.requires_grad = True` after the reshape, it works:

```
a = torch.tensor([1.])
a = a.reshape(a.shape)
a.requires_grad = True
b = torch.tensor([1.])
c = torch.cat([a,b])
d = torch.sum(c)
d.backward()
```

Seems like a bug in PyTorch, because after this `a.requires_grad` is still true.

```
a = torch.tensor([1.])
a.requires_grad = True
a = a.reshape(a.shape)
```

This seems to be related to the fact the `a` is no longer a leaf in your "Doesn't work" example, but still a leaf in other cases (print `a.is_leaf` to check).